# HSQL & Hibernate: unsupported internal operation: Session

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hsqldb

I have a project with the following dependencies:

```
hibernate-entitymanager-4.1.8
hsql-2.2.8
```

I have a Persistence Unit including:

```
<properties>
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver"/>
    <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider"/>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect"/>
</properties>
```

And an Entity with a field thus:

```
@Lob
@Column(name = "DOCUMENT")
private String document;
```

When I come to persist through the EntityManager my entity I'm seeing the following end of stack trace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: unsupported internal operation: Session
at org.hsqldb.error.Error.runtimeError(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.Session.performLOBOperation(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.types.ClobDataID.nonSpaceLength(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.types.CharacterType.castOrConvertToType(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.types.CharacterType.convertToType(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.StatementDML.getInsertData(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.StatementInsert.getResult(Unknown Source)
```

Am do doing something obviously wrong here? This was working albeit with quite a few changes and on a different machine. Possibly a result of a dependency upgrade or a switch to JPA/Hiberate from a straight Spring/Hibernate abstraction layer.

Several others reporting much the same thing found via Google but no particular solution :(

Answer (score 2):

This issue has been fixed in the latest version of HSQLDB. Version 2.3.0 is available from hsqldb.org.

Answer (score 2):

A fix in Hibernate 4.1.8 created a regression. For HSQLDB, Schema export will create a blog/clob limited to 255 char.

[When using HSQLDB, inserting any CLOB value larger than 16Mb always fails with an exception](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-7541)

[Pull request](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/pull/376/files)

Answer (score 0):

I even tried with newer version HSQLDB 2.4.1 and Hibernate-core 5.3.6, the problem still persists.
Because Hibernate generates schema with only 255 char column length, in my case, try to alter column type works (clob instead of clob(255))

`alter table public.user alter column myClobColumn clob`