# hsqldb hibernate persist @Lob

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, hsqldb

I'm trying to persist a long string to database (exception's stacktrace), we use HSQLDB (2.2.9) for tests and Postgre for runtime.

1) I annotated field like

```
@Lob
private String someBigMessage;
```

2) Wrote migration DDL script (flyway but no matter)

```
..., some_big_message text, ...
```

3) It migrates OK, but when I perform JUnit test, which uses hsqldb I'm getting this:

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement
...
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement
...
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement
...
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: unsupported internal operation: Session java.lang.RuntimeException: unsupported internal operation: Session
...
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: java.lang.RuntimeException: unsupported internal operation: Session
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks.

Comment: As per this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/14738657/174184, this issue has been fixed in ver 2.3.0. Consider upgrading.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. I checked it before, but if there is a workaround without upgrading I'll choose it. I can't believe that nobody persisted @Lob before 2.3.0, it is a such common operation :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have migrated to 2.3.1, got error in a same place, but with more specific explanation:

HsqlException: data exception: string data, right truncation
Then added annotation @Column:

```
@Lob
@Column(length=20971520)
private String someBigMessage;
```

Then migrated back to 2.2.9 and it works!